# Selenium cannot find element by name or id (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate logging into a website using selenium, but I am getting "no such element message" error. Here is my code, with the link to the website included:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\Family\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://login.microsoftonline.com/c4d72b4d-8155-4a90-9155-7705148c41ca/saml2?SAMLRequest=jdE9a8MwEAbgvdD%2fYLRbkh3ZVoQdCO0SSJek7dClnJVzYrClVCeX%2fvw6DaEdu90HLzzc1espntwOPyakmGweG0YwDuHav3eqqFSHOZRQKZAZdJDpDjToKisXiCx5xUC9dw3LuWTJhmjCjaMILs4jmWepVKnMnrPCyNIscq601pVUbyxZE2GIc%2fbBO5pGDHsMn73Fl922YacYz2SEiAdqOQ4IwfXu6F2E0HtuQRzyQQxnAbNeDP7YO3Fxby8Vn3cs%2bRoHRw2bgjMeqCfjYEQy0Zr9%2bmlrZq45Bx%2b99QNb3d8lSf2DD%2f8Jwo3OVjdokdlSVrZKUS10quTSphrLIi00drrVebksWh7RzYch3ob%2beIp0Bovc%2bvGXXosrYgbV4u9nVt8%3d&RelayState=%2fd2l%2fhome&sso_reload=true")

login_button = driver.find_element_by_id("i0116")
login_button.send_keys("sajjad.jessa@student.tdsb.on.ca")
```

And here is the element I am trying to access with my code:

```html
<input type="email" name="loginfmt" id="i0116" maxlength="113" lang="en" class="form-control ltr_override input ext-input text-box ext-text-box" aria-required="true" data-bind="
                    externalCss: {
                        'input': true,
                        'text-box': true,
                        'has-error': usernameTextbox.error },
                    ariaLabel: tenantBranding.UserIdLabel || str['CT_PWD_STR_Username_AriaLabel'],
                    ariaDescribedBy: 'loginHeader' + (pageDescription &amp;&amp; !svr.fHideLoginDesc ? ' loginDescription' : ''),
                    textInput: usernameTextbox.value,
                    hasFocusEx: usernameTextbox.focused,
                    placeholder: $placeholderText" aria-label="Enter your TDSB email address here, then click Next" aria-describedby="loginHeader" placeholder="Enter your TDSB email address here, then click Next">
```

From other answers I understand that you have to use driver.find_element_by_css_selector() and driver.switch_to.frame(), but if you look at the full hypertext of the website, the first frame to go into is a "div" tag without any attributes. It is however the only "div" tag alongside two "script" tags. I need the correct code to go into the frame, or another method to automate logging in.

Comment: have you tried to open the same url in different browser, f.e firefox, does it have same id?if not it's dynamic one and try to avoid using it. moreover, is not there ifame tag on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems synchronization Issue.
Induce `WebDriverWait()` and wait for `element_to_be_clickable()`

```
login_button =WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"i0116")))
login_button.send_keys("sajjad.jessa@student.tdsb.on.ca")
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

---

```
login_button =WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"loginfmt")))
```

Comment: Can this be done using elements other than ID also found in driver.find_element_by such as class_name or link_text? Also, would time.sleep() suffice to synchronize?

Comment: Yes this can be done using other locator such as name , class, xpath & css selector. time.sleep() is a bad practice try to avoid that this unnecessarily slowdown your automated scripts.

Comment: What is the syntax for the other locators? Using the same line with ID at the end replaced is not working for me.

Comment: `login_button =WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME,"loginfmt")))`

Answer (score 0):

The most of the large websites now uses dynamic layout. You should look for the parents with static css selector, and then do something like that:

```
.parent_css_selector > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > img > input
```

Token '>' is supposed to look only for direct childs, token ':nth-child' asserts to the child number in parent.

Example:

```
<div class="parent_css_selector">
    <div id="random_id_12312313">
        <div id="unneccesary_123123"></div>
        <div id="random_id_341234">
            <form id="random_id_345545">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span>
                    <input id="neccesary_13843942"></input>
                </span>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can use this selector to access the input:

```
.parent_css_selector > div > div:nth-child(2) > form > span:nth-child(5) > input
```